# How to print DBX print std::string?

Tags: c++, solaris, dbx

I am working on Solaris and would like to print `stl::string` in dbx.
Which command should I use to print it? print is not working.

Comment: You mean `std::string`?

Comment: supposedly you are supposed to use [`print *variable*`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1380/blagg.html#blagk)

Comment: yes, sorry for typo. std::string

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
std::string str;
```

This will print the entire object:

```
(dbx) print str
```

On Solaris 11.2, using Solaris Studio 12.3, this will print just the value of the `std::string`:

```
(dbx) print str.__data_.__data_
```